# Define sign ambiguous pointer parameter for a function

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, programming-languages

Is it possible to define a sign ambiguous pointer parameter for a function in C and/or C++?

For example, say i have a function that works on both unsigned and signed types of a 8-Bit variable and the function takes a pointer to the variable to be processed/manipulated.

I know i can typecast with (unsigned char*) or (signed char*) but im looking for something cleaner.

```
unsigned char Var1;
signed char Var2;

void MyFunction(unsigned char* Var);

MyFunction(&Var2); // This creates an error
```

With that said i like to bring up the thought i had that languages higher than assembly shouldn't be using names such as BYTE / WORD / DWORD or QWORD to define a variable with an explicit sign type. I say this because these are size operators for assembly and don't actually define a sign. The sign in assembly is picked by the instruction chosen. Yet i see these names used everywhere in C/C++ and defined as unsinged, at least on windows. This seems like a conflict of interest to me...

Comment: Are you aware of `void*` or templates?

Comment: 1.  You mean "signedness" not "sign".  2.  C and C++ don't have separate operators for signed and unsigned operations, the behavior is determined by the type.  So it is natural that the type is not just a size (as you want) but also imbues semantics.

Comment: @Tas void* works for removing the required sign but now the size isn't explicit. The size can only be 8-bit and any sized variable can be passed with void*.

Comment: What's unclean about typecasting?

Comment: @BenVoigt I aware C/C++ dont have separate operators for signed and unsigned operations. Read the last part of my post.

Comment: And seriously? a down vote within 1 sec of posting? did you even read the full post people? I think i bring up an interesting thought at the end of my post!

Comment: @ChristianGibbons nothing unclear about it. just looking for something cleaner. If possible.

Comment: You could define two functions, where one uses a typecast to call the other.

Comment: You most likely got downvoted for mixing C and C++.

Comment: Why would that matter? C and C++ are very similar languages! I wanted a solution that i could put into a header file that i could use for both C and C++. Like how writing a C or C++ program on windows (visual studio) uses the same Windows.h file. This project is for developers, not just me. That's why i was looking for a clean method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With C, you have limited options.  You can do the typecasting that you don't like when you call the function:

```
void MyFunction(unsigned char* Var);

int main(void) {
    unsigned char Var1 = 5U;
    signed char Var2 = 5;

    MyFunction(&Var1);
    MyFunction((unsigned char *)&Var2);
}
```

you can use `void *` and typecast in the function itself and just not pass the wrong type of pointer to it:

```
void MyFunction(void* Var);

int main(void) {
    unsigned char Var1 = 5U;
    signed char Var2 = 5;

    MyFunction(&Var1);
    MyFunction(&Var2);
}
```

Or if you *really* want something beyond that, you can use a _Generic macro to automagically typecast it for you.  It may or may not be the "best" approach, but I think it will accomplish your goal.

```
#define MY_FUNCTION_HELPER(X) MyFunction( _Generic((X), \
   char *: (unsigned char *)X, \
   signed char *: (unsigned char *)X, \
   unsigned char *: X \
   ) \
)

void MyFunction(unsigned char *Var);

int main(void) {
    unsigned char Var1 = 5U;
    signed char Var2 = 5;

    MY_FUNCTION_HELPER(&Var1);
    MY_FUNCTION_HELPER(&Var2);
}
```

The last one works by using the C11-introduced `_Generic` which allows a form of polymorphism to use different expressions based on the type of a controlling expression.  In this case, if `X` is `char *` or `signed char *`, it will perform a typecast to `unsigned char *`.  If `X` is already `unsigned char *`, it will remain as such.  If `X` is anything else, it will fail to compile as no other types are accounted for in the generic association list.

Comment: Thanks!. The _Generic method is probably gonna be the closest i get in these languages.

Answer (score 1):

If the logic for the two types of objects is the same, your best option is to use a function template.

```
template <typename T>
void MyFunction(T* Var);
```

If you want to restrict the use of the function only for 8-bit types, you can use a `static_assert` in the implementation.

```
template <typename T>
void MyFunction(T* Var)
{
   static_assert(sizeof(T) == 1, "Wrong type. Can only deal with 8-bit types.");
   ...
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Yea that could work but not for my particular case cause the function is actually written in assembly and declared in C/C++ and called from there.

Comment: +1 up-vote for ya since you had an answer that would have worked if the function itself was written in C++